# php mvc .htaccess can't turn of skip if file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a .htaccess file for an mvc framework. Most people recommend to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is that RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f means if the file path actually exists then go to that file instead of submitting the name to index.php. I don't want that to happen. I want everything to be submitted to index.php no matter what. So when i take that line away, The url isn't submitted to index.php anymore. It just always says that index.php was submitted to index.php. Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is there for some purpose. If you remove that line even request for your css, js, images files will also be forwarded to `index.php`. Do you really want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want everything to be submitted to index.php no matter what.

Well, apparently you want everything *except* the index.php file, so not exactly "no matter what", try using this condition instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

> Also the links now have ?url=page attached to it. how would i make it not show that?

Add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?url=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```